# How do you hide the Extended Validation text in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ssl, about-config

Certain sites have Extended Validation certificates. On top of the normal lock symbol, Firefox also shows the Organization name next to the lock symbol in green text. This gives users a nice, warm, fuzzy feeling knowing that nothing can happen to them *cough* *heartbleed* *cough*.

However, this text can take up a fair amount of space, eating into the URL. I don't always run Firefox maximized, and it looks very crowded when the extended validation text cuts off half of the previously available URL space or more.

Is there a setting in about:config that can be set to disable the text from showing? That is, make firefox treat Level 3 SSL certificates as the same as Level 1.

[image: Firefox Extended Validation Text covering URL and part of search]

Note: this screenshot is from Nightly, so it may just be a bug that the EV text overlaps all of the URL and part of the search bar. But even still, I want to be able to hide the text, not fix a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Hide the site identity labels

> The Site Identity Button is a Firefox security feature that gives you more information about the sites you visit. You can quickly find out if the website you are viewing is encrypted, if it is verified, who owns the website, and who verified it.
>
> <sub>Source: [How do I tell if my connection to a website is secure?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure)</sub>

*Credit goes to Gingerbread Man for the original technique. Tested with Firefox 29.0.*

1. Close Firefox.
2. Add the following code to your `userChrome.css` file:

   ```css
   #identity-icon-labels
   {
       display: none !important;
   }
   ```

   It is located in the `chrome` subfolder inside your [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox). Create one in case it doesn't exists already. Here's an example: [userChrome-example.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome-example.css).

   **Note** Apparently `!important` doesn't seem to be needed and could be omitted.
3. Start Firefox again.

### Screenshots

#### Before

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### After

[image: Screenshot 2]

### References

- [How to Remove Security/Site Identity Info from Location Bar?](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2652863)

---

## Disable the OCPS validation

> The **Online Certificate Status Protocol** (**OCSP**) is an [Internet protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol) used for obtaining the revocation status of an [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) [digital certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_certificate).
>
> All versions of [Mozilla Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) support OCSP checking. [Firefox 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3) enables OCSP checking by default.
>
> <sub>Source: [Online Certificate Status Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol)</sub>

To answer this question:

> Is there a setting in `about:config` that can be set to disable the text from showing? That is, make [F]irefox treat Level 3 SSL certificates as the same as Level 1.

Yes, there is. The following has been tested with Firefox 29.0.

1. Type `about:config` in the Firefox location bar.
2. Change the value of the `security.OCSP.enabled` preference to `0`.

As an alternative, follow these steps:

1. Open the Firefox **Options** dialog.
2. Select the **Advanced** tab, and click the **Validation** button.
3. Uncheck the **Use the Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) to confirm the current validity of certificates** option, and click **OK**.

### Screenshots

#### Before

[image: Screenshot 3]

#### After

[image: Screenshot 4]

### Additional information

> A green padlock plus the name of the company or organization in green means that website is using an [Extended Validation (EV) certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). An EV certificate is a special type of site certificate that requires a significantly more rigorous identity verification process than other types of certificates. While the gray padlock indicates that a site uses a secure connection, the green padlock indicates that the connection is secure and that the owners of the domain are who you would expect them to be.
>
> With the EV certificate, the Site Identity Button assures you that [paypal.com](http://paypal.com/) is owned by Paypal Inc., for example. Not only does the padlock turn green on the Paypal site, it also expands and displays the name of the owner in the button itself.
>
> <sub>Source: [How do I tell if my connection to a website is secure?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure)</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to specify a maximum width for the site identity info instead of completely hiding it?